# saveInBackground throws exception "unsaved ParseObject"

Tags: android, parsing

I'm trying to save an item which has a relation to my image class. I can save the item, and i can save the image seperately, but when I am saving them with the relation if throws this error:

```
unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject
```

Here is my code:

```
myAdvert = new ParseObject("Items");
myAdvert.put("title", "some title");
if (pic1Set) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) pic1.getDrawable())
                    .getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    myPhoto1 = new ParseObject("Images");

    filePhoto = new ParseFile("image.png", byteArray);
    filePhoto.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                myPhoto1.put("image", filePhoto);
                ParseRelation relation = myAdvert.getRelation("pictures");
                relation.add(myPhoto1);
                myAdvert.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (e != null) {
-->                         // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN!!!!
                            Log.d("error", e.toString());
                        } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.d("wow, error", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error saving: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

lets consider this a comment and some extra info rather then an answer -

I'm running to the same exception when trying to login BUT it will happen only after I have some action done offline while the local data store is working
I also have ACL on.
I'm guessing it has something to do with an attempt to save stuff pinned from my offline work in a wrong order or something.

I'm working on debugging mine - good luck to all of us - let me know if you find something.

Comment: You just need to save the parseObject before you can add it to a relationship.

Comment: Well I wasn't trying to add a relation - it's happening to me somtimes when trying to save an object and sometimes when trying to signup a user.

I'm guessing its the objects in local data store that the ACL need to link to the user - and when becoming online something is getting messed up.